Sending FedAuth cookies with Submit Form POST request, results in a NullReferenceException on UmbracoFormsController.SubmitForm method
When submitting a form request via the UmbracoFormsController, i am receiving a HTTP 500 Response with a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. displayed in the log in the SubmitForm method.
This only occurs when sending FedAuth cookies with the Cookie header on the request, which we use for our own custom authentication. On the same page, the form can be submitted successfully without error when not logged in (and thus the FedAuth cookies are not sent with the request).
We are using Umbraco version 7.15 and a very old Forms version 4.4.2.
What i tried:

Upgrading Umbraco Forms to version 6 and 7 does not seem to resolve the issue.
Increasing the size allowed for the request header

What can i do to resolve this issue? If possible, I would like to avoid having to upgrade Umbraco to a higher version, even though I am aware that the current one we are using is out of support.
